# Centering images on reports - Report Builder 10.1.2.0.2

Tags: oracle, report, oraclereports

We are using Report Builder 10.1.2.0.2, and when we place images on these RDFs, they aren't always centered. Is there a method to get these images perfectly centered? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

1. create **frame** which contains that image (if you created it *after* the image, you'll have to [Layout - Move Backward] it). Select both frame and image

   - stretch the frame so that it covers area that should contain that image in its center
   - in my example (see screenshot), I aligned it to report margins
2. Go to [Layout - Alignment] menu
3. Choose "Align center" for

   - both "Horizontally" and "Vertically", or
   - only one of them, if it is appropriate for what you're doing

Once you click the OK button, image will be aligned into the center of the enclosing frame.

[image]